# Does the tape recorder on Voyager-1 still work?

Tags: voyager, data-storage

I'm preparing a talk on data storage for an ASME meeting. Given that it's 20 billion km away, I want to quote Voyager I as the "largest control loop" in existence. I'm guessing the tape recording capability is no longer used, but is it still true that someone here on earth could press a button and 18 hours later the tape would start running and 18 hours after that we could pick up the data with the deep space network. I want a "gee-whiz" start to the talk so appreciate any help on interesting aspects or anecdotes, etc. (I see the discussion on angular momentum, for example) 
- Roger

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Edit: The [Spacecraft operations schedule](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/mission/status/#sfos) contains the answer. On December 18, 2021, we see an item 'PLAYBACK' show up in the schedule for Voyager 1.

[image: Schedule]

S/C 31 is Voyager 1. The 'PLAYBACK' label is the data playback itself, this takes about 6 hours at 1.4 kbit/s. Before playback you can see 'X/B HI POWER', which switches the transmitter to high power mode (18 instead of 12 W).

'31 DSN Coverage' shows the antennas that are used. '55' is DSS 55, one of the antennas at the Madrid station. They're using 4 antennas (at Madrid) in an array: DSS 63 is the 70-m antenna, the others are 34 m diameter (DA = downlink pass in an array, R is the array reference antenna).

At various other times in the schedule you'll see 'TAPPOS', which I'm guessing is a Tape Position command, in preparation for recording PWS data.

---

This part was written in 2016. The tape recorder on [Voyager 1 is still in use:](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/science/index.html)

> Science data are returned to earth in real time at 160 bps. Real time data capture uses 34 meter Deep Space Network (DSN) resources (see below) with the project goal to acquire at least 16 hours per day of real time data per spacecraft. This goal is not always achieved due to the competition for DSN resources with prime mission projects and other extended mission projects.
>
> Once a week per spacecraft, 48 seconds of high rate (115.2 kbps) PWS data are recorded onto the Digital Tape Recorder (DTR) for later playback.  An additional 48 seconds are recorded each week on Voyager 1.  These data are played back to Earth once every 6 months per spacecraft and require 70 meter DSN support for data capture.

The [Deep Space Network](http://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/about/#) (DSN) is a series of large dish antennas used by NASA to communicate with deep-space missions like Voyager. The DSN includes dishes with a diameter of 34 m and a few with a diameter of 70 m.
There are only a few antennas this large in the world, so they are shared between various deep-space missions.

On Voyager 2, [DTR operation was ended in 2007](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/spacecraft/spacecraftlife.html):

> Voyager 2 DTR operations was no longer needed due to a failure on the high waveform receiver on the Plasma Wave Subsystem (PWS) on June 30th, 2002.

The JPL site lists a [cutoff date in approx. 2018](http://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/spacecraft/spacecraftlife.html):

> limited by ability to capture 1.4 kbit/s data using a 70 m/34 m antenna array. This is the minimum rate at which the DTR can read-out data.

I'd expect it to be possible to play back some data from the DTR into Voyager's RAM, then transmit at a slower rate from RAM. The JPL site doesn't mention this possibility, though.

Comment: What's a 34 meter Deep Space Network?

Comment: That is really astounding! This is an actual tape recorder? Magnetic tape? I'm imagining an [8-track cassette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:1978_AMC_Matador_sedan_red_NC_detail_of_factory_AM-FM-stereo-8-track_unit.jpg) and other "stuff" from the 1970's, but any chance you can find a picture of what it *actually* looked like?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  [here's](http://deepspace.jpl.nasa.gov/about/DSNComplexes/34meter/#) one

Comment: I haven't been able to find one of voyager's, but galileo also had one and there are quite a few pictures of one of those units that's on display somewhere.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: the Deep Space Network is a series of large dish antennas used by NASA to communicate with deep-space missions like Voyager. the DSN includes dishes with a diameter of 34 m and a few with a diameter of 70 m.

Comment: More info on Voyager DTR: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2053/how-was-magnetic-tape-decay-prevented-in-voyager-1/2454#2454 , photo of Galileo DTR: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2272/on-which-device-data-gets-saved-on-spacecrafts/2273#2273 , I searched for photos or drawings of the Voyager DTR for one of these questions but couldn't find any.

Comment: It would take much more time, but if Voyager repeated telemetry twice or thrice, the effective strength could be improved. Or perhaps by ganging multiple dishes. All of which would take up even more of DSN's increasingly crowded resources, however.

Comment: 'a 70 m/34 m antenna array' indicates they would gang 1x 70 m and 1x 34 m antenna.

Comment: Well you can't really spool much tape into RAM because Voyager's computers have 32kbytes RAM, a good chunk of which is program code.

Comment: Appreciate all the great feedback! Looking at several images of the Galileo tape-recorder, you can see the tape-path is arranged 
so the two spools rotate in opposite directions.  If the empty spool has the same moment of inertial as the tape that's 'missing' within the spool ID, then you can convince yourself that the net angular momentum will be zero irrespective of tape position.  Likewise presumably the capstan and the rotating guides should all add up to zero angular momentum as a group. Wondering if this care was taken in the Galileo design but maybe not in Voyager design?

Comment: @uhoh I hadn't seen this image before - supposedly of the Voyager 1 tape recorder:  https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/galleries/images-of-voyager/#gallery-4

Comment: @RogerWood lovely!

Comment: @Hobbes - Is this still true (as of January 2022)?  That is, is Voyager 1 still using its DTR?  I thought both Voyagers had been in transmit-only mode for several years now.  Is that not true?

Comment: @honeste_vivere I found the answer and I've updated my reply.

Comment: Very cool update.

Comment: @Hobbes appreciate the update!  It blows my mind.  I started my career on tape recorders around the time Voyager was launched.

Comment: @Hobbes - I think both Voyager spacecraft have been running on real time telemetry for a while.  That is, they immediately transmit whatever they record.  I'm not sure how this is done precisely, as it's 50+ year old technology.  Regardless, I gave you a +1 for an excellent answer.

Comment: @honeste_vivere yes. The schedule shows several hours a day of DSN download at 160 bit/s. That's realtime coverage. The PWS on Voyager 1 is the only instrument left that uses the tape recorder.

Comment: @Hobbes I watched a video by Astrum https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=leiqMYUOOUQ saying the tape recorder was switched off some time ago. I look at the SFOS Editor you referenced for the beginning of this year and see that PLAYBACK is mentioned but nothing else that indicates that it's actually the tape that is being used.  So I assume Astrum is correct?

Comment: I'm not convinced Astrum is right. The 2023-01-25 SFOS schedule shows a playback session at 1400 bits/s, and the only device that can provide data at that speed is the tape recorder.