# How does Voyager 1 keep track of its orientation?

Tags: attitude, voyager

With the Voyager 1 attitude correction all over the news (related: [How do Voyager 1's Trajectory Control Thrusters differ from its Attitude Control Thrusters?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23895/how-do-voyager-1s-trajectory-control-thrusters-differ-from-its-attitude-control)), I wonder with what instrument such a spacecraft can measure its own attitude towards earth in the first place.

How do we know exactly what its attitude is so that the thrusters can accurately be fired?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Voyager 1 and Voyager 2 use the same Attitude and Articulation Control Subsystem (AACS) to maintain the crafts orientation; facing the antenna towards the Earth.

Voyager's AACS system uses a sun sensor for yaw and pitch reference, and a star tracker trained continuously on a bright star at right angles to the sun point for a roll reference.

Links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_1#Spacecraft_components

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyager_program#Computers_and_data_processing

http://www.au.af.mil/au/awc/awcgate/jplbasic/bsf11-2.htm

Comment: related information: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23896/12102

Comment: Also related: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3093/746